# Suspend, resume, shutdown work in legacy but not UEFI in 16.04LTS on HP AMD/Radeon desktop?

Tags: boot, uefi, suspend, shutdown

I had Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit dual-booting (with Windows) on an HP Pavilion (see below for specs), and it worked fine.

Since wiping and installing 16.04 64-bit as only OS...suspend, resume, and shutdown do not work properly.

Attempts to boot from live disk have confirmed that I have some problems with suspend, resume, and shut down when booting from live disk USB in UEFI mode. However, when booting from live disk CD in legacy mode, everything works fine.

PROBLEM:  Suspend turns off the screen, but leaves the fan running and leaves on the "on" light on the computer. Attempts to resume via keyboard press and power button press/hold are from that point completely unsuccessful. Can't even turn the computer off by holding the power button, in this state: I have to unplug the power cable to be able to turn it off and back on.

Shutdown freezes on the purple "Ubuntu" screen with the dots frozen. From this state, I am able to turn off the power by holding the power button and then turn back on with the same button.

I have tried completely wiping/reinstalling, again, with the same results. I get the same results from systemctl suspend and systemctl poweroff as I do from using the GUI.

**Kernel**: Linux 4.4.0-89-generic (x86_64)
**Distribution**: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
**Processor**: AMD A6-3600 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 4 
**Graphics**: Gallium 0.4 on AMD SUMO (DRM 2.43.0 / 4.4.0-89-generic, LLVM 4.0.0)

Results of *lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'*:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6530D] [1002:964a]
```

EDIT: I just went ahead and reinstalled in legacy boot mode, and that fixed the problem; but why would these problems happen with UEFI?

Comment: You need to check for a BIOS update for your HP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for the suggestion. I ended up reinstalling in legacy boot mode (which I had to do via CD, in my case), instead, and that fixed the problem for me.